# Spring mutual relationship of entities

Tags: java, spring

I have the following user entity.

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdAt", "updatedAt", "roles", "enabled",
    "authorities", "credentialsNonExpired", "accountNonLocked", "accountNonExpired"})
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class User extends Base implements UserDetails, Serializable {

@Size(min = 4, max = 20)
@NotNull
private String username;

@NotNull
private String password;

@NotNull
@Email
private String email;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

private List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return roles.stream().map(r -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(r.toString())).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
}
```

I want user to have a list of books but I am facing different kind of error in different trials. When I put @OneToMany annotation over bookList attribute, I get this error

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.example.demo.model.User.bookList, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

In some sources, it said to use @OneToMany like @OneToMany(mappedBy = "xxx", 
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER) and in this case in the Book entity, I should add user attribute and use @ManyToOne but I do not want book entity to have user attribute. How can I handle this?

This is getBooks method in User service.

```
@Transactional
public GenericResponse findAllBooks(User user) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(user);
    return genericResponseService.createResponseNoError(user.getBookList());
}
```

And I cannot have to fetchtype eager attribute in the same model, it throws

```
Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException
```

Note: I do not want to use EAGER fetch type.

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, you want to map `User` to `Book` as OneToMany. But only in one direction, from User to Book, not the other way around.
For this purpose, you can use unidirectional OneToMany mapping.

```
public class User extends Base implements UserDetails, Serializable {
    ...

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="book_id")
    private List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();

    ....
}
```

Note: You'll need *JPA2.X* for this, it's not supported by *JPA1.0*.
You learn more about how to use `@JoinColumn` [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Unidirectional_OneToMany,_No_Inverse_ManyToOne,_No_Join_Table_(JPA_2.x_ONLY))

Comment: But this uses EAGER fetching.

Comment: @Davis You can set the fetch type to LAZY. But then you should not try to access the `bookList` from a `User` object outside the database transaction, otherwise you will get a lazy initialization exception, has you have already experienced. (You'll need to be aware where the boundaries of the transaction are and only access `bookList` while inside the transaction).

Comment: Change it to FetchType.LAZY and then fetch the data using -> JOIN FETCH (JPQL).
String String = "select u from User u join fetch u.books b where u.username = :username".

And your Entity class does not have an @Id field..

Comment: I handled the problem by using findByUsername first in the get books method. So it loaded lazy data.

Comment: The default fetch type for `@OneToMany` is Lazy. So no need to mention it explicitly in that case.